# python prime number generation

Tags: python, algorithm

Below is the code for printing n prime numbers in python. This program works fine, but i want to know the control flow. And the else statement does not match with it's previous if condition. If I try aligning it to the if condition, the execution throws an error. What exactly is happening here.

```
candidate = 3
count = 2
#n is the number of prime numbers to be printed.
n = 10
print("2")
while(count < n):   
    for x in range(2, candidate):
        if(candidate % x == 0):
            break
    else:
        print(str(candidate))
        count +=1       
    if(count <= n):
        candidate+=1
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing it yourself?

Comment: For/else is a construct in python. Please see the language reference: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html section 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python allows you to specify an `else` block for a `for` statement.

The `else` block is executed after the `for`, but *only* if the `for` terminates normally (not by a break).

Without this feature, you'd have to use an extraneous flag variable to keep track of this state.  So, in your case, the `else` block would be executed iff `(candidate % x == 0)` was never true.

Comment: Is there any such implementation in java? Or rather, how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You'd achieve the same functionality by using a flag to track that state.  For example, set it to `true` before you break, then only run the code in the `else` block if that flag was false.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement this same program in java?

Answer (score 2):

## `else` belongs to `for` loop

If you read the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), where the code comes from, you find there also the explanation.

You can read it as "what shall be executed, if the main loop completes without exceptions."